# What is this lambda expression with Unity Resolver doing

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, unity-container

Looking through someone else's code I found this line of code:

```
     protected IDirectIp Iridium => _resolver.Resolve<IDirectIp>();
```

I was confused seeing a lambda (=>) instead of an equal sign (=). The dependency injection library is Unity, is this syntax specific to Unity?

Could anyone explain what this expression is doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an expression bodied function. This was added in c# 6.0 and is equivalent to

```
protected IDirectIp Iridium
{
    get { return _resolver.Resolve<IDirectIp>(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a shortcut added in C# 6.0 for defining the `get` body of a readonly property

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodies-on-property-like-function-members

Answer (score 1):

It is an [expression bodied](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/16101a/expression-bodied-members-a-new-feature-of-C-Sharp-6-0) member from C# 6.0.

It is just shorthand for a  property getter that returns everything after the `=>`.